# Does software exist that will analyze my previous hands and tell me what it thinks I did wrong?

Tags: poker-tools

It would be even better if it syncs up with Holdem Manager 2 (I'm very new to Holdem Manager 2) still on the trial trying to learn the program.

I want some assistance on where any holes in my game may be as I want to begin to move up to higher stakes.

I play on Full Flush (only for a single tournament I tend to almost always cash in) otherwise I play on Americas Card Room (only because Holdem Manager 2 supports it) (if any other better site works with Holdem Manager 2 for US players let me know!).

I basically want a program that analyzes my past hands and tells me if I did the wrong/right thing.  Does such a program exist?

Maybe this exists in Holdem Manager and I am just not familiar enough with it.

Comment: Be better than your opponents at relevant game. If you want this, need this, etc...go for it. More in it for developers than introspective players willing to look back at documented hands and make progress...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is too basic or not substantive enough to address your question, but PokerTracker has a view of aggregate stats called "LeakTracker" that might be a good place to start. This isn't about specific hands, but it could point out areas where your play diverges from best practices. After identifying potential problem areas where your history of play diverges from traditional "best practices", you could then use the filters to find specific hands that demonstrate some of what the app considers suboptimal play. It also offers views of this data broken down by position, and you can apply other filters too. It would be a multi-step process where you first identify a broad area where you might be losing value and secondly finding specific hands to replay and study that demonstrate that broad area. It's also a good way to explore the PokerTracker app and the extremely granular filtering that it offers. I am not sure what Holdem Manager has that's similar to this, but since their feature sets overlap substantially, I bet there's something similar.

[image]

Comment: HoldemManager has that as well I will have to give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you're not going to find any software out there that's going to tell you if you made the right decisions on a hand by hand or street by street basis.  One of the great things about poker is that there's rarely a completely, objectively correct decision.  There are so many factors to consider during a hand;  this makes it interesting for humans, but tough for computers.  Different players can profit the same from different styles of play, so which style is correct?

Fortunately, there is a ton of software and websites out there that can *assist* you with determining what the best play would be for the hands you want to look at.  These mostly take care of calculations such as pot odds, expected value, the approximate value of your chips during a tournament, understanding your opponents' general tendencies, etc.  But you still have to put the pieces together and make the ultimate determination of what is correct.

I have not used Holdem Manager 2 and haven't used Holdem Manager in a while, but I mainly used it as a tool for keeping track of of aggregate stats--my own overall play and the tendecies of my most common opponents--and for looking for holes in my game by parsing through the various stats it can give (and looking for changes to those stats over time).  For disecting indvidual hands, I think the best option is still to go over them by yourself meticulously--using software for calculations--and by participating in online forums (or having a group of really great poker-playing friends!).

Comment: I guess that was a bit too much to ask.  I'm more looking for obvious things like.  Hand 2304:  You called a bet on the turn with incorrect pot odds.  It would then let me replay the hand and show me pot odds, etc.  So yes assisting in saying things like, pot odds, expected value.  I understand it can't say with 100% you made the right/wrong decision but more like flags for unusual behavior in my play.

Comment: I don't know if there's any tool that would neccessarily flag specific hands for you to look at, but if you can find or keep track of questionable hands on your own, Holdem Manager does have a hand replayer where you can go over the hand with pot odds and equity displayed. You may have to play around with some of the options to display this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Leak buster is exactly what you are looking for. It analyzes your game, finds mistakes and helps to avoid them in future. It's a really useful thing and it helped me a lot to become a better player.

Answer (score 0):

Leak finder is kind of like pointing your metal detecter at a large field and hearing it go off. You know there's something there but you're probably not going to be looking in the right place for a long time, and more than likely end up wasting a hell of a lot of time that you could have saved by even hiring the cheapest coach on the internet or just anyone to walk through the hands with you. Software can do numbers and it's only just starting to get context. I'm actually working on a contextual software-coach that is the humanized version of PokerSnowie I guess you could say. Model-to-data as opposed to data-to-model and back and forth which it seems like they probably did with Snowie.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this one (Disclosure: I'm the developer)
https://ezanalyzer.net

Comment: Product recommendations should be supported with an explanation of how they meet the needs of the person asking the question. See this Meta post for further discussion poker.meta.stackexchange.com/q/290/88